# custom phtml added in layout not display

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout, phtml

i wrote a custom module, which includes a phtml placed at

```
\app\design\frontend\mytheme\default\template\checkout\cartrelated\cartrelated.phtml
```

i added a line

```
    <block type="cartrelated/cartrelated" name="cartrelated.cartrelated" 
template="checkout/cartrelated/cartrelated.phtml"></block>
```

in

```
\app\design\frontend\mytheme\default\layout\checkout.xml
```

the phtml not displaying, anyone know what is the problem?

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rayman_Cartrelated>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </Rayman_Cartrelated>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
          <cartrelated>
            <class>Rayman_Cartrelated_Block</class>
          </cartrelated>
        </blocks>
        <models>
          <cartrelated>
            <class>Rayman_Cartrelated_Model</class>
          </cartrelated>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

the cartrelated.phtml just contains echo 'abctest'

here is the content section of checkout.xml

```
        <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.empty.widget" as="checkout_cart_empty_widget" translate="label">
                <label>Empty Shopping Cart Content Before</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml" after="-" />
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                <label>Shopping Cart Items Before</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <!--<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>-->
            <block type="cartrelated/cartrelated" name="cartrelated_cartrelated" as="cartrelated" template="checkout/cartrelated.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.extra" translate="label">
                <label>Checkout Forms Extra</label>
            </block>

            <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.widget" as="checkout_cart_widget" translate="label">
                <label>Shopping Cart Items After</label>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>


            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
        <label>Additional Product Info</label>
    </block>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: Can you add your config.xml

Comment: Can you refresh your cache and also disable compilation

Comment: @Rohit already do that so many times

Comment: Can you add in which handle you have added your block?

Comment: Could you add the content of checkout.xml?

Comment: did you try with `<block type="core/template" name="cartrelated.cartrelated" 
template="checkout/cartrelated/cartrelated.phtml"></block>` it is working?

Comment: @qaisar yes, tried

Comment: it is working or not?

Comment: not working. : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.empty.widget" as="checkout_cart_empty_widget" translate="label">
                <label>Empty Shopping Cart Content Before</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml" after="-" />
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                <label>Shopping Cart Items Before</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <!--<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>-->
            <block type="cartrelated/cartrelated" name="cartrelated_cartrelated" as="cartrelated" template="checkout/cartrelated.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.extra" translate="label">
                <label>Checkout Forms Extra</label>
            </block>

            <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.widget" as="checkout_cart_widget" translate="label">
                <label>Shopping Cart Items After</label>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>


            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
        </block>
    //add your bloc here 


 <block type="cartrelated/cartrelated" name="cartrelated.cartrelated"  after="-"
template="checkout/cartrelated/cartrelated.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
```